# Parametrize a plane, two alternatives?

Tags: calculus, vectors, parametrization

I need help parameterizing the following (is it a plane?)

$$
-a/2\leq x\leq a/2\\
-b/2\leq y \leq b/2\\
z=z_0\quad  (\text{constant})
$$
I have two attempts, but I not sure which one is correct.

Attempt 1:

Let $x=s$, $y=t$, so $\mathbf r(s,t)=(s,t,z_0)$
where, $s\in[-a/2,a/2]$ and $t\in[-b/2,b/2]$.

Attempt 2:

Let $x=as/2$, $y=bt/2$, so $\mathbf r(s,t)=(as/2,bt/2,z_0)$
where, $s\in[-1,1]$ and $t\in[-1,1]$.

Comment: Both are correct (parametrisation is not unique), and your object is a rectangle with side lengths $a$ and $b$.